# How Are Facebook Doing These Redirects?

Tags: c#, facebook, google-chrome

I've come across something that's puzzled me for the past 3 hours regarding Facebook's login procedure.

I visited http://m.facebook.com (with UA Spoofer installed and set to Nokia Lumia User-Agent) and proceeded to log-in whilst monitoring the headers. I purposely entered the wrong password for an account I have.

When pressing log-in it sends a POST request to this URL: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?refsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&refid=8 the status code returns a 200 response code.

Then instantly afterwards it does a GET request to this URL: http://m.facebook.com/login.php?refsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&refid=8&e=1348022&email=frankthebutcher%40hotmail.com&signup_layout=layout%7Cbottom_clean%7C%7Cwider_form%7C%7Cprmnt_btn%7Cspecial%7C%7Cst%7Ccreate%7C%7Cheader_button%7C%7Chdbtn_color%7Cgreen%7C%7CFeb1&li=jFMuUdDWbmFhq8b-zAjEOHnE&_rdr

Which is the URL that says the password was incorrect.

But, where is that redirect coming from? There is nothing in the response headers from the first POST request, and JavaScript isn't enabled.

Try it on Chrome. Would love to know how it's doing that so I can adjust the mobile app I'm developing accordingly.

**Solved:** In my mobile app I was sending the POST request to the right URL, but the URL string I used was encoded which was causing the problem.

Comment: Probably a `Location:` header being sent back with the first request (which your browser then runs with after the response has been processed).

Comment: I've been through the headers with a fine tooth comb, there's nothing in there that I can see.

Comment: Yeah, a lot of mobile applications rely on the Global Positioning System so it can adjust which server to login to.

Comment: I just tried it, and did what I thought: send back a `Location: http://m.facebook.com/login.php?refsrc=...` header back.

Comment: @BradChristie ah, didn't notice you edited your comment. Interesting, I will certainly take a look at that.

Comment: @BradChristie Post it as answer and I'll vote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first POST request is sending back a `Location` header which tells the browser to step-ahead from this request and proceed with the next. The second request is just the browser then using that new `Location` supplied and moving forward.

here's what you see from the first POST response:

[image: Screenshot of response eheader]

However, from what I can see it's a `302` ([redirection: found](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3)) response, not a `200` OK. Something tells me that you're judging the response headers on the final request, not the intermediate redirect/handoff.

Comment: Out of interest does the AllowAutoRedirect property of HttpWebRequest (C#) follow the Location header?

Comment: @JamesJeffery: Since it's a 3xx address, it will follow (unless the property is set to false, or the hop count has been exceeded)

Comment: I don't even see a location header when I monitor the headers. Are you using an older UA so it loads the WAP page and not the regular Facebook mobile page?

Comment: @JamesJeffery: Do you have it set to "preserve logs upon navigation"? IIRC, chrome clears the log between page views, so you'll only ever see the last request (which, in this case, is the redirected result and any assets on the page)

Comment: I've got "Preserve Log Upon Navigation" set.

Comment: @JamesJeffery: then I'm not quite sure, but i can see the location header in every client i try (w or w/o the UA altered).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25243/discussion-between-james-jeffery-and-brad-christie)